# Having difficulty in understanding how Promises work

Tags: javascript, promise

I have a piece of code where I fetch a JSON file from my local disk:

```
var modelData = fetch("./modelData.json")
       .then((res) => res.json())
       .then((val) => console.log(val)
```

And doing this I can perfectly see the JSON data in my browser console. However when I do this:

```
    var modelData = fetch("./modelData.json")
           .then((res) => res.json())
           .then((val) => val)
console.log(modelData)
```

I see a `promise(pending)` in my console. I know how async JS works, and I know that the chained then() fires only when the previous promise is resolved. My question is, in my second then() block, why can I see the data when I console.log() it but cant see the date when I return it from the same function where I was console.logging it?

Also, if I consider the fact that maybe in the second case the promise wasnt fulfilled when I console.logged it, due to the async nature of fetch(), I tried the following:

```
var modelData = fetch("./modelData.json")
           .then((res) => res.json())
           .then((val) => val)
setTimeout(()=>console.log(modelData), 1000)
```

thinking that once the promise is fulfilled, I will surely get my value. But then I get

> Promise(fulfilled)

. Can anyone tell me what I am missing? I will be really grateful for any help.

Comment: Read everything here. It was an eye opener for me when I learned promises: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult at first understanding this concepts. I'm going to change a bit your code:

```
var promise = fetch("./modelData.json");
promise.then((res) => res.json())
    .then((val) => console.log(val);
console.log(modelData)
```

As you see, is the same code. I create a promise and set what I want to do when become resolved. That you get is an object (the promise) that will run your fetch and, on success, will invoke your "then" funcion.

But the variable "promise" (modelData in your question) is always a promise. Never has data about your model.

Imagine that instead of fetch, you invoke some setTimeout function with 60 seconds of delay. Your console.log is going to be exectuted inmediatly and it's impossible that in that moment you have the results of your funcion, apart from that the objct is a promise, not your fetched data.
But debug the code, imagine that you enter into the promise code and after 60 seconds, you enter in the "then" function. Inside that function is where you have available your data. It's for that what you work with the results inside the then function, never outside.

Answer (score 2):

You can't "unwrap" a Promise, but you shouldn't even have to.

A Promise **is not** a placeholder for the real data that will magically turn into it once it arrives. It's a handle, through which you can access the data the same way no matter if it has already arrived or will only arrive later.

For that reason, anything returned from a `then` callback will always be wrapped in another promise, so that it's still not possible to directly access it from the outside.

If we have the following code,

```js
//`Promise.resolve` is added just for the sake of illustration (it wraps its argument in a promise similarly to what `then` does)
const p1 = Promise.resolve(fetch("./modelData.json"))
const p2 = p1.then((res) => res.json())
const p3 = p2.then((val) => val)
```

...we can visualise the structure like this:

```
        Promise.resolve(  fetch(...)  )
        vvvvvvvvvvvvvvv   vvvvvvvvvv
 +------+++++++++++++++   ++++++++++
 |                         |
 v                        vvv
p1 ---------------- .then(res => res.json())
                     vvvv        vvvvvvvvvv
 +-------------------++++        ++++++++++
 |                         +-----+
 |                         |
 v                        vvv
p2 ---------------- .then(val => val)
                     vvvv        vvv
 +-------------------++++        +++
 |                         +------+
 |                         |
 v                         v
p3  • • • • • • • • .then(... => ...)
```

As you can see from that, another `.then` would be required to access the value in `p3`.

That is why `console.log`ging *inside* a `then` can print the real value, while `console.log`ging outside will only give you a promise.

Answer (score 1):

The `fetch()` function and `then()` method both return a `Promise` object. You assigned that `Promise` object to `modelData` and it will stay as a `Promise` object and will not be reassigned to the fulfilled value automatically.

To get the fulfilled value, you could either use the `then()` method or `await keyword`.

```js
// name it `modelPromise` to be clear
const modelPromise = fetch("./modelData.json")
           .then(res => res.json())
           .then(val => val)

modelPromise.then(val => console.log(val))

// `await` can only be used inside an async function
async function main() {
  const value = await modelPromise;
  console.log(value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```js
    var modelData = fetch("./modelData.json")
           .then((res) => res.json())
           .then((val) => {
               console.log(val)      
            })
```

The reason for `Promise(fulfilled)` is because javascript runs sync instead of async so you would need to chain .then like above or run it in an async block.

```js
const printmodeldata = async () => {
     const data = await modelData;
     console.log(data);
}

printmodeldata();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do a `setTimeout()` based approach then the following will probably work (it all depends on how long the promise will take to be fulfilled).

```js
var modelData;
fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/3")
       .then((res) => res.json())
       .then((val) => modelData=val);

setTimeout(()=>console.log(modelData),100);
```

But in the end this is not any easier than simply placing your console.log() into the final `.then()`. With this approach you can be sure to get the result as soon as the promise is fulfilled. And, as a bonus, the received result will be available for further event-driven interactions in the global variable `modelData`.

```js
var modelData;
fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/3")
       .then((res) => res.json())
       .then((val) =>{
  modelData=val;
  console.log(modelData);
});
```